# Remove first character when it's a comma

Tags: mysql

How can I remove the first `,` from the field `bla` in the table `jo`?

So `,how,r.you` should be `how,r.you`

But don't remove the `,` when it's `how,r.you` to begin with

Comment: Use explode function ..with comma and remove first index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before printing data you could do this

```
$trim = ltrim('how,r.you', ',');
echo $trim;
```

it will output this *how,r.you*

Comment: Do you know what table, field and mysqli is? ^^

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT bla FROM jo";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $trim = ltrim('how,r.you', ',');                                                                                                                echo "BLA: " .$trim . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>`

Comment: Sry thats not it, I need to remove the leading comma from the fields

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: update jo set bla = replace(bla, ',%', ''); <== this is what I'm trying to do but it's not working

Comment: This query will work for you. Try this                                                 `UPDATE jo SET bla = CONCAT(REPLACE(LEFT(bla, INSTR(bla, '%')), '%', ''), SUBSTRING(bla, INSTR(bla, '%') + 1))`